# Kali Linux takes way too long to load the GUI after entering the password? IPTABLES

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, connection, kali-linux

After entering the passward to login, it takes way too long to load GUI.

I think the issue is with the firewall, when I enable it the GUI loads way two long to load. More than a minute, if it's disabled it loads within 3 to 5 sec.

Steps I took:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo apt install iptables-persistent
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo systemctl status netfilter-persistent
sudo systemctl start netfilter-persistent
sudo systemctl enable netfilter-persistent --> This is the issue, it takes more than 2 minutes to load gui
sudo systemctl disable netfilter-persistent --> This solves but the filtration is off, it takes 3 to 5 sec to load gui
```

These are the few lines among hundreds of them from `dmesg`:

```
Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:bc:62:d2:a7:d1:60:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:bc:62:d2:a7:d1:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.255 LEN=116 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22737 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=47464 DPT=7121 LEN=96
```

System:

```
 Static hostname: kali-raspberry-pi
       Icon name: computer
Operating System: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.44-Re4son-v7l+
    Architecture: arm
```

Help me troubleshoot the issue and fix it without disabling the firewall.

Comment: Why do you have "-P INPUT", or did you mean "-A INPUT" ?